# How to find the first minimum?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to find the first minimum of `Sin[a (b + m)]`. For example: In the second row, since 0.9092<0.9589, I would like to assign `0.9092` as the minimum instead of `0.4201`.

**CODE:**

```
data = Table[{a, b, m, Sin[a (b + m)]}, {a, 1, 2, 0.5}, {b, 2, 3, 1}, {m, {-1, 2, 10}}];

FormatCells[table_] := With[{minPosition = OrderingBy[Abs@table, Last, 1]},MapAt[Item[#, Background -> Green] &, TableForm[{#}, TableDirections -> Row,TableHeadings -> {None, {"a", "b", "m", "F"}}] & /@ table,minPosition]]
FormatTable[table_] := Grid[FormatCells /@Abs@table, Dividers -> All]
FormatTable[N[data[[1]]]]
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**EDIT 1:** I had missed out a part of the code which I have added now.

**EDIT 2:** Please help me export the minimum values to a `.csv file` (Using Ulrich Neumann's answer given in the addendum) as shown in this screenshot:[image]

I have tried the `Export` command in several ways but nothing works. I will truly appreciate any help.

Comment: The question is completely incomprehensible: What might be the first minimum of `{{1., 3, -1, 0.909297}, {1., 3, 2, -0.958924}, {1., 3, 10, 0.420167}} ` ???

Comment: There is `Abs` applied to the `table` values, therefore I'm trying to find the first minimum of `0.909297, 0.958924, 0.420167` which is indeed `0.909297`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pickMin[list_] := Pick[list , MinDetect[list ], 1][[1]]
Map[pickMin@Abs@#[[All, -1]] &, Flatten[data , 1] ]
(*{0.536573, 0.909297, 0.279415, 0.14112, 0.909297, 0.544021}*)
```

to get the Min-values of `|Sin[a(b+m)]|`

The correct position of these minima follow with

```
Map[FirstPosition[MinDetect@Abs@#[[All, -1]], 1] &, Flatten[data,1]] 
(*{{3}, {1}, {2}, {1}, {1}, {2}}*)
```

**addendum**

Here QP's corrected code

```
FormatCells[table_] := With[{minPosition = 
     FirstPosition[MinDetect@Abs@#[[All, -1]], 1] &[table]}, 
  MapAt[Item[#, Background -> Green] &, 
   TableForm[{#}, TableDirections -> Row, 
      TableHeadings -> {None, {"a", "b", "m", "F"}}] & /@ table, 
   minPosition]]
FormatTable[table_] := Grid[FormatCells /@ Abs@table, Dividers -> All]
FormatTable[N[Flatten[data, 1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: It would be very helpful if the output looks like the one that I am getting with my present code but with `0.909297` as the minimum in the second row. This is because the code that I have posted is actually a part of a bigger program that I have.

Comment: I seriously can't thank you enough. You have solved my problem! @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: You're welcpme!

Comment: Also, how can I export these first minimum values to a .csv file? I have tried `table = First@MinimalBy[#, FirstPosition[MinDetect@Abs@#[[All, -1]]]] & /@ data[[1]];
Export["Data 1.csv", table, TableHeadings -> {"a", "b", "m", "F"}]`, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Try `table = First@
    MinimalBy[#, FirstPosition[MinDetect@Abs@#[[All, -1]]]] & /@ 
  Flatten[data, 1 ]` and `Export["c:\\Mathematica\\Data1.csv", table, "Table", 
 TableHeadings -> {"a", "b", "m", "F"}]`

Comment: The first minimum values are not getting exported. Also, using `table = First@MinimalBy[#, FirstPosition[MinDetect@Abs@#[[All, -1]]]] & /@ data[[1]]; Export["Data 1.csv", table, TableHeadings -> {"a", "b", "m", "F"}]`, the first column values are getting exported instead of the first minimum values. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your goal: What values should `table` provide? Obviously more than `a,b,m,F`? Why  `MinimalBy`?

Comment: Try `indexMin = 
 Map[FirstPosition[MinDetect@Abs@#[[All, -1]], 1] &, 
   Flatten[data, 1] ] /. {a_} :> a;
MapThread[#1[[#2]] &, {Flatten[data, 1], indexMin}]` to get correct table

Comment: Please see my edited question. The **accepted answer** is perfect, I now only want to export those values as shown in the screenshot of `.csv` file.

Comment: My last comment gives exactly this table !

Comment: But I don't understand how to export it to a .csv file

Comment: In one of my last coments I gave you the code for `Export`

Comment: Can you please include how to export (the green values) to a .csv file in your answer?

Comment: Here are the three codelines which you already know: `indexMin =   Map[FirstPosition[MinDetect@Abs@#[[All, -1]], 1] &,     Flatten[data, 1] ] /. {a_} :> a; table =MapThread[#1[[#2]] &, {Flatten[data, 1], indexMin}];Export["Data 1.csv", table, "Table", TableHeadings -> {"a", "b", "m", "F"}]`

Comment: When I use the above code, this is what I get: `"a  b m F"
"1. 2 10 -0.5365729180004349"
"1. 3 -1 0.9092974268256817"
"1.5 2 2 -0.27941549819892586"
"1.5 3 -1 0.1411200080598672"
"2. 2 -1 0.9092974268256817"
"2. 3 2 -0.5440211108893698"`
But I want only the green values (as shown in the screenshot) to get exported

Comment: Each row contains exactly the green values

Comment: Oh great! It's a good idea to exclude "`Table`" from `Export` so that the values come in separate cells. THANK YOU once again and sorry for bothering you so much :D